# Largest eigenvalue scaling in a certain Kac-Murdoch-Szegö matrix

Tags: eigenvalues, limits-and-convergence, toeplitz-operators

I'm looking at $N\times N$ matrices $M_N$ with elements
$$M_N=\left( \rho^{|i-j|} \right)_{i,j=1}^N,$$
where $\rho$ is a complex number of unit modulus. 
These matrices with $\rho\in\mathbb R$ and $|\rho|<1$ have been studied in detail before, with a nice exposition to be found [here](https://works.bepress.com/william_trench/133/), which includes some more references.

In the cited article, there is an implicit form of the eigenvalues, given through
$$ \lambda_j = \frac{1-\rho^2}{1-2\rho\cos\theta_j+\rho^2}, $$
where $\theta_j$ are roots of the following function
$$ G(\theta) = \sin[(n+1)\theta]-2\rho\sin[n\theta]+\rho^2\sin[(n-1)\theta]. $$
(Even though only real $\rho$ were considered in the article, this works for complex $\rho$ also.)

Intriguingly, if $\rho=e^{i\phi}$, the largest eigenvalue of $M_N$ seems to be essentially independent of $\phi$ (as long as $\phi$ is sufficiently different from 0 (i.e., $\mathcal O(1/N)$).
Since the inverse of $M_N$ is almost tridiagonal (see the [article](https://works.bepress.com/william_trench/133/) for its form), it can be efficiently diagonalized numerically. I've checked up to $N=10^6$ and the largest eigenvalue (mostly real) seems to *almost* follow a power law (roughly $N^{0.85}$), but not quite. In fact, it looks slightly curved, so perhaps it is approaching $N$.

Another important thing I've noticed is that the $\theta$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue is very close to $\phi$, and seems to approach $\phi$ as $N\to\infty$. Indeed, it is the same scaling as the actual eigenvalue $\lambda$, which follows from the fact that $\theta=\phi$ makes the denominator of the formula for $\lambda$ vanish. Expanding $\theta=\phi+\delta\phi$ it becomes clear that $$\ln\lambda\to -\ln(\theta-\phi) + \text{const.} $$

So I've been trying for a long time to extract how $\theta$ approaches $\phi$ from $G(\theta)$, but failed. I'd appreciate any pointers to a solution.